# Breeze error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: '' - call fetchMetadata first

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm trying to save new item to my database using Breeze and web api.

Here is my model:

```
 public class MuscleGroup
    {

        #region Properties

        public int MuscleGroupId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Navigational properties

        public virtual ICollection<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }



        #endregion
    }
```

Here is my API:

```
[BreezeController]
    public class MuscleGroupController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly EFContextProvider<MadBarzDatabaseContext> _contextProvider =
            new EFContextProvider<MadBarzDatabaseContext>();


        // GET api/<controller>
        [HttpGet]
        public IQueryable<MuscleGroup> Get()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Context.MuscleGroups;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }
    }
```

Here are parts of my dataService.js:

```
app.angularModule.service('muscleGroupService', function(breeze, logger) {


    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

    var mbservice = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: "http://localhost:23758/api/MuscleGroup",
        hasServerMetadata: false,
    });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: mbservice });

    manager.enableSaveQueuing(true);

    var removeItem = breeze.core.arrayRemoveItem;

    var items = [];

    var muscleGroupService =
    {
        getAll: getAll,
        getSucceeded: getSucceeded,
        getFailed : getFailed,    
        addItem: addItem,
     //   deleteItem: deleteItem,
     //   updateItem : updateItem,
    };

    return muscleGroupService;


    //#region addItem

    function addItem(initialValues) {
        var item =  manager.createEntity("MuscleGroup", initialValues);
        saveChanges().fail(addFailed);
        items.push(item);
        return item;

        function addFailed() {
            removeItem(items, item);
        }
    }

    //#endregion

    //#region SaveChanges
    function saveChanges() {
        return manager.saveChanges()
           .then(saveSucceeded)
           .fail(saveFailed);
    }

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
        logger.success("Saved :D");
        logger.log(saveResult);
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        logger.error(error);
        logger.log(error);
    }
    //#endregion
}
```

Here is part of my controller:

```
$scope.addNewItem = function() {
        var newItem = muscleGroupService.addItem({ Id: 42, Name: $scope.Name, Description: "ho", ImageUrl: "hey"});
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
    };
```

And this is error I get:

```
Error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'MuscleGroup'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first.
    at proto._getEntityType (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:6056:19)
    at proto.getEntityType (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/breeze.debug.js:6047:21)
    at Object.addItem (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/app/AdminMuscleGroup/MuscleGroupService.js:61:45)
    at Object.$scope.addNewItem (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/app/AdminMuscleGroup/MuscleGroupController.js:16:42)
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:6365:19
    at http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:12987:13
    at Object.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:8057:28)
    at Object.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:8137:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/angular/angular.js:12986:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:7122/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js:3063:9) angular.js:5754
```

I query All Muslce groups before I try to add antoher.

Comment: Are you using MetaData from the server?  If so when you are configuring your service you are stating you are not using serverMetaData, which it sounds like that is not true, based off your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PW Kad is giving you the clues.

When you wrote `hasServerMetadata: false`, you told Breeze not to get metadata from the server; you told Breeze that you would provide the metadata on the client. You aren't providing metadata on the client.

You're controller doesn't have a `Metadata` endpoint ... and couldn't offer such an endpoint AND ALSO be structured as the controller-per-type API controller that you seem determined to devise.

You're deviating from the standard Breeze productivity path while pursuing controller-per-type. That's fine ... after you have a little experience, know what you're doing, and know why you're doing it. The `hasServerMetadata` flag is true by default for a reason; you can't just set it false and expect everything to work.

I suggest that you back up, follow the Breeze guidance, understand it, then depart from that guidance incrementally as you discover solid, business reasons for doing so.

Comment: Thanks, I exactly did that, until now I was only looking trough sample ToDo, but now I've studied documentation more carefully and lot of things are clearer to me now